# What word means a “male temptress”?

Tags: synonyms, suffixes, grammatical-gender, gender-positive, derivational-morphology

I was trying to describe a man who entices others into making bad decisions. I have several closely related questions:

1. Is it okay in English to refer to a man as a *temptress*?
2. Is there a uniquely male version of *temptress*?
3. Is there a good strategy or rule for changing words like *temptress* into their male equivalents — if those exist?

Comment: Seducer, charmer, debaucher.

Comment: temptress / female; tempter / male

Comment: Is it okay in English to refer to a man as a temptress? Why? Is your bohyfriend giving you grief?

Comment: I revoked the answer, I guess I saw something that seemed suitable and selected it. Hopefully this will give more of a chance of people have better answers.

Comment: I am actually rather curious about temptation in general, but sexual temptation is the one that I think gets most commonly associated with the word temptress. So to answer, no, not just sexual temptation.

Comment: Giggleo. Seductive giggling male.

Comment: A "salesman", if he is any good . . .

Comment: There's no "male temptress." Please rephrase the title. The body of the question is better.

Comment: +1. Yes, Matt, people tend to interpret certain words used in your OP ie, "*seduce*", "*temptress*", exclusively with "*sexual*" enticement. And because I read your OP as a request for a term **not specifically sexual** I didn't go for the typical "**seducer**" angle, i.e., *Don Juan* etc. You might want consider editing your post to clarify that you are seeking a general, rather than a specifically sexual, term for a man who tempts others into making bad decisions.

Comment: Moreover, the choice of *temptress* is clearly wrong as the question does not relate to the usual meaning of that word. The question itself may need to be rewritten.

Comment: Kind of *manipulator*: "**1** A person who controls or influences others in a clever or unscrupulous way." (ODO) http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manipulator

Comment: Big ups to Hot Licks for debaucher.

Comment: I don't believe there is any single word (either for male or female).  Instead, there are a number of words, and which one (if any) is appropriate depends on factors such as what sort of decisions we're talking about, the person's motivations, and the person's methods.  "Temptress" is only appropriate when the method used is sexual attraction, for example.

Comment: I'm voting to close, surely any dictionary would have told the OP that *temptress* is gender specific? NO ONE has attempted to answer question No.3.  We have the gender-specific  words such as: *actress* (m) *actor*, *waitress* (m) *waiter*, *policewoman* (m) *policeman*; *songstress* (m) *songster*, etc. and then gender neutral words such as *scientist*, *doctor*, *teacher*, *film director* etc.. All stuff you can find in any dictionary.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

*-ess* is, in fact, a feminine suffix. The male or neuter form (English tends to conflate the two) would be *tempter*. As a note, the title The Tempter, with capital letters, is given to the Devil.

A person who tempts in a sexual fashion might be called a *seducer* (*seductress* if female).

Comment: There used to be a *coquet* to go along with the *coquettes*.  Actually, I rather think a few of those might still be around. :)

Comment: Sadly, the OP does not seem to be referring to *that* kind of a person ;) at all. The fault is with the way the question is frame, though.

Comment: @Kris The OP did say *seduce* not *trick*, eh now?

Answer (score 27):

A mythological creature called *succubus* is described as the ultimate temptress, using sexual seduction to lure its prey. The male counterpart, *incubus*, similarly uses sexual seduction to lure in prey. These terms can be used to describe seductive people whose ultimate goal is self-serving or else makes no consideration for the wellbeing of the person being seduced.

Similar mythological creatures with less sexual overtones include *sirens* and *will-o-wisps*. These are less about seducing and more about distracting or enchanting their prey, but you could still use these terms to suggest the meaning you're looking for.

Comment: Do note many people will wrongly associate incubus with [incubator](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incubator), which has nothing to do with the intent of OP.

Comment: too bad so sad for those who are easily confused by the English language. i'd go with incubus.

Comment: @Mast - I am *shocked* by the Google NGram for [succubus vs incubus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=succubus%2Cincubus&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuccubus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cincubus%3B%2Cc0).  Apparently, the latter is significantly more common than the former, when I would have expected the reverse.

Comment: @Bobson I suspect the difference is because of the band Incubus, not because the mythological creature is better-known.  In fact, I'd wager fully half the people familiar with the Incubus in modern-day USA heard it first on *Supernatural*.

Comment: @gatherer818 - That makes a lot of sense.  It definitely explains the uptick since 1999.

Answer (score 22):

```
                    Temptress / Feminine; Tempter / Masculine
```

**OP also requests a description of "a man who entices others into making *bad decisions*"**

Such an individual is sometimes referred to as a “**Svengali**”

> **svengali** *n*.: A person who manipulates or controls another, especially by force of personality for malicious purposes. See, the Free Dictionary [**svengali**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Svengali)

Comment: As per your recommendation, I actually switched the quoted section in your answer. Is Svengali a proper noun?

Comment: Not in this usage.

Comment: Worth noting for reference that svengali [can be seen as an anti-Semitic term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svengali).

Comment: @Garry - yes, I became aware of that as I researched the answer. Because I'd heard the term, from time to time, all my life - without anti-Semitic intent - I chose to go ahead with it because it doesn't have to be used with that repugnant connotation. I'm not an "anti-people" person and find myself strongly attracted to all underdogs, being such a "dog", myself.

Comment: @LittleEva, In an effort to avoid potentially offensive speech (though temptress already walks the line a little bit) I think I'm going to go ahead and select on of the other answers. Your input has been very helpful, though, in determining the specifics of how to ask my question. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, Matt, I appreciate your sensitivity. I would add that all terms which would come anywhere near to meeting the OP's request are, by nature, pejorative terms ... though I certainly didn't offer "Svengali" as an attempt to insult, anyone or any culture.

Comment: While probably less obscure than quomodocunquize, the word svengali is sufficiently obscure that I wouldn't wholeheartedly recommend its use.

Answer (score 12):

If you mean bad financial or professional decisions, the word you're looking for might be *charlatan*:

> A person practising quackery or some similar confidence trick in order to obtain money, fame or other advantages via some form of pretense or deception. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlatan))

A similar word is *huckster*:

> A pejorative for a person who sells something or serves biased interests, using pushy or showy tactics. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huckster))

Answer (score 11):

My suggestion would be "*Lothario*"

> "a man who obsessively seduces and deceives women." ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lothario?s=t))

Answer (score 5):

Try [**Pied Piper:**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied_Piper_of_Hamelin)

> The Pied Piper of Hamelin [...] is the subject of a legend concerning the departure or death of a great number of children from the town of Hamelin (Hameln), Lower Saxony, Germany, in the Middle Ages. The earliest references describe a piper, dressed in multicolored ("pied") clothing, leading the children away from the town never to return. In the 16th century the story was expanded into a full narrative, in which the piper is a rat-catcher hired by the town to lure rats away with his magic pipe. When the citizenry refuses to pay for this service, he retaliates by turning his power that he put in his instrument on their children, leading them away as he had the rats.

---

> [EXAMPLE SENTENCES](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Pied-Piper?q=pied+piper)
>
> *Out on the streets in these impoverished areas east of the Tigris River, they are like Pied Pipers, leading a trail of dozens of children behind them within minutes of arriving in a neighborhood.*
>
> *But before I get to genuflecting villagers, let me talk about my role as a Pied Piper.*
>
> *No wonder a succession of diet experts have become the Pied Pipers of the modern age.*

(Definition from Wikipedia; example sentences from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: Great answer.  This is the word I'd use, and I have used it in similar situations.

Comment: Who can account for the vicissitudes of taste or public opinion?

Answer (score 4):

A [snake-oil salesman](http://www.davemanuel.com/investor-dictionary/snake-oil-salesman/) would  deceitfully   tempts you into taking a bad decision (  buying or doing something).

- It generally  refers to a person that is pushing a product that is deemed to be overhyped at best, and fraudulent at worst but,  but it may be  figuratively used to refer to someone you deceitfully tempts you into doing somethnig that is not in your interest but just in his own.

Answer (score 3):

A [*pickup artist*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickup_artist) perhaps?

> A pickup artist (commonly abbreviated PUA) is a person who practices
>   finding, attracting, and seducing sexual partners. Such a person
>   purportedly abides by a certain system deemed effective by that
>   community in their attempts to seduce partners.

Answer (score 2):

[*Con artist*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/con_artist). If you must have the male gender, consider [*conman*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conman) or *con man*, or give props to [Melville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_Melville) by using [*Confidence-Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Confidence-Man).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an adjective to use in a specifically sexual context then I really like *louche*.

Comment: and louche means?

Comment: that's a neat word. bit obscure or outdated though don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

The term I usually hear is "Adonis", which comes from Greek mythology.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adonis

However, this term is not common.

Comment: Where in that wiki does it say anything about an Adonis "enticing others into making bad decisions"?

Answer (score 0):

Lothario, giggolo, kokopelli - take your pick.

Comment: *lothario* [has already been proffered](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/234559/106801).

Comment: Please explain what makes any of the options good choices.